# Gmail API HistoryRequest query

Tags: gmail-api, google-api-client, google-api-dotnet-client

To do a full sync, I can use ListRequest and pass a query (ex inbox only - `label sent -label:sent OR to:me`). How can I do the same for a partial sync - using HistoryRequest? I don't see the possibility of passing in any query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the labelId for a history request